# Creating VM's with Ubuntu fails to install Domain

Tags: server, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, vnc

I am trying to install an Ubuntu 16.04 VM an Ubuntu 16.04
Actually I was trying to install Volumio on a VM, but because that didn't work I tried to install Ubuntu as a VM but got the exact same result described below:

My Problem is that the installation always seems to hold when trying to create the domain. See the output below:

```
jan@JHK-SRV:~$ sudo virt-install --virt-type=kvm --name TestUbuntu -- ram=1024 --vcpus=1 --hvm  --cdrom=/var/lib/libvirt/boot/ubuntu.iso --graphics vnc --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/Ubuntu-vm1,size=8,bus=virtio                                WARNING  Graphics requested but DISPLAY is not set. Not running virt-viewer. 
WARNING  No console to launch for the guest, defaulting to --wait -1 
Starting install...
Allocating 'Ubuntu-vm1'                                     | 8.0 GB  00:00
Creating domain...                                          |    0 B  00:00
Domain installation still in progress. Waiting for installation to complete.
```

This does not change over time.

If I interrupt the installation and list all VM's using:

```
list virsh
```

the output is that the VM is running.

```
    Id    Name                           Status
   - - --------------------------------------------------
    1     Volumio                        laufend
    3     TestUbuntu                     laufend
```

Whenever I try to connect to the console of the VM with:

```
virsh console TestUbuntu
```

I only get an empty console which I can't exit with CTRL+C.
As I don't know any other way to exit the console I cold reset the PC...

Has anybody encountered this problem before? If so, has anybody found a solution?

I'm relatively fresh to using the console and to virtualization so any comprehensive guides you could recommend me would be very appreciated.

Comment: Related: http://serverfault.com/questions/537667/virt-install-kvm-cannot-open-display